# CK finder not able to load XML response from web server

Tags: ckfinder

I have an issue with CKFinder 2.1.1. When I click the button that's supposed to load it, it loads the window but it comes up with a response that says "It was not possible to load the XML response from the web server. The server returned an empty response." The javascript function that loads CKFinder is posted below. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
$('textarea.contentEditor').ckeditor(function(){},
{
   //Options~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   resize_enabled : false,
   height : 600,
   fontSize_defaultLabel : '12',
   font_defaultLabel : 'Arial',
   //scayt_autoStartup : true,
   extraPlugins : 'contentPreview',
   contentsCss  : [ 
                $('#SITE_ROOT').html() + "/css/base/StandardWellness.css",      
           $('#SITE_ROOT').html() + "/css/base/CKEditorOverrides.css"                  
        ],
  toolbar :
  [
     { name: 'document', items : [ 'Source','-','DocProps','Print','-','Templates' ] },
     { name: 'clipboard', items : [ 'Cut','Copy','Paste','PasteText','PasteFromWord','-','Undo','Redo' ] },
     { name: 'editing', items : [ 'Find','Replace','-','SelectAll','-','SpellChecker', 'Scayt' ] },
     { name: 'forms', items : [ 'Form', 'Checkbox', 'Radio', 'TextField', 'Textarea', 'Select', 'Button', 'ImageButton',                
         'HiddenField' ] },
     '/',
     { name: 'basicstyles', items : [ 'Bold','Italic','Underline','Strike','Subscript','Superscript','-','RemoveFormat' ] },
     { name: 'paragraph', items : [ 'NumberedList','BulletedList','-','Outdent','Indent','-','Blockquote','CreateDiv','-',
        'JustifyLeft','JustifyCenter','JustifyRight','JustifyBlock','-','BidiLtr','BidiRtl' ] },
     { name: 'links', items : [ 'Link','Unlink','Anchor' ] },
     { name: 'insert', items : [ 'Image','Flash','Table','HorizontalRule','Smiley','SpecialChar','PageBreak','Iframe' ] },
     '/',
     { name: 'styles', items : [ 'Styles','Format','Font','FontSize' ] },
     { name: 'colors', items : [ 'TextColor','BGColor' ] },
     { name: 'tools', items : [ 'Maximize', 'ShowBlocks','-','About' ] },
     { name: 'MyHealth', items : ['contentPreview']}
  ]

}).ckeditor(function(){
   //Callback   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   var editor = $('textarea.contentEditor').ckeditorGet();               

   CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, { basePath : '../ckfinder/', rememberLastFolder : true  } ) ;

   CKEDITOR.on( 'dialogDefinition', function( ev )
   {
  // Take the dialog name and its definition from the event data.
  var dialogName = ev.data.name;
  var dialogDefinition = ev.data.definition;

  if ( dialogName == 'image' ) {
     dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Upload' );   
     call_obj = new Object();                  
  }

  if ( dialogName == 'flash' ) {
     dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'Upload' );   
  }

  if( dialogName == 'link' ) {
     dialogDefinition.removeContents( 'upload' );   
  }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Double check for errors in your ckeditor/config.php file. 
I was having the same issue until I figured out there was a typo in there.